# Celery tasks are not adding object to db Django/Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, docker-compose, celery, django-celery

I have trouble with celery using it in docker, it receives tasks and in terminal sends that everything works fine, but it creates nothing in the database(I use Postgres). I think that problem somewhere in docker, but not sure. Consol doesn't give any errors. Can't find anything in the internet about it, please help me with this problem

[image]

my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
       - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
       - ./app:/app
    command: >
       sh -c "python manage.py wait_for_db &&
              python manage.py makemigrations &&
              python manage.py migrate &&
              python manage.py test&&
              python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

    environment:
       - DB_HOST=db
       - DB_NAME=app
       - DB_USER=postgres
       - DB_PASS=supersecretpassword
       - CELERY_BROKER=redis://redis:6379/0
       - CELERY_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
       - db
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    environment:
       - POSTGRES_DB=app
       - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
       - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword

redis:
   ports:
     - "6379:6379"
   image: redis:5-alpine

celery-beat:
  build: .
  user: root
  command: celery -A app beat -l INFO
  environment:
    - DB_HOST=db
    - CELERY_BROKER=redis://redis:6379/0
    - CELERY_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
  depends_on:
    - db
    - redis
    - celery

celery:
  build: .
  user: root
  command: celery -A app worker -l INFO --pool=solo
  environment:
    - DB_HOST=db
    - CELERY_BROKER=redis://redis:6379/0
    - CELERY_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
  depends_on:
    - db
    - redis
```

my celery.py

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from app.settings import INSTALLED_APPS

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')

app = Celery('app')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()


app.conf.beat_schedule = {
   'add-every-5-seconds': {
      'task': 'transactions.tasks.create_transaction',
      'schedule': 5.0,
    },
}
```

and my task

```
@shared_task
def create_transaction():
   transaction = Transaction.objects.create()
   return transaction.id
```

Comment: I assume your Postgresql container runs at the default port `5432`? I can't see it in your environment variables, have you set the port's value correctly in in Django's settings.py? Also maybe you can try replacing `DB_HOST=db` with `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` but I'm not sure if it even works.

Comment: Yes, Postgresql at port  5432. Tried DB_HOST=127.0.0.1, it's not worked. I'll check settings.py, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finelly I found out the reason. The problem was in wrong Celery configuration in settings.py. Thanks to Niel Godfrey Ponciano for pointing me to that thing!